# Unsupported features Document

Tags: documentation, project-management

Do we have any specific document artifact in software projects to specify what is not supported in your software or what features you have not implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may define the scope of a project (which implies the software artifacts) by an In-Out-List, as described by [Alistair Cockburn](http://alistair.cockburn.us/) in *Writing Effective Use Cases*. You can access the relevant part here: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=26061

The In-Out-List is a simple document that lists features in a table and marks them as part of the project or not.

[arc42](http://confluence.arc42.org/display/templateEN/arc42+Template+%28English%29+-+Home) defines what is out of scope as part of the [System Scope and Context](https://github.com/arc42/aquagrails/blob/master/src/docs/arc42/03-System-Scope-and-Context.asciidoc).

In our projects we define the scope of a project with our template called [Out Item](https://www.smartics.eu/confluence/display/PDAC1/Out+Item) (it is part of our commercial product for [Confluence](https://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence)). The structure is very simple: A description of the unsupported feature and a reason why it is out of scope. Since every out-item is on a separate wiki page it is easy for us to render them according to their metadata. But it is basically the same as described in the In-Out-List.